# Protagonist becomes the avatar of an alien deity and has to cope with adversary god

Tags: story-identification, aliens, religion

I read this at least 20 years ago, and I believe it was originally published in the '60s.

The main character is a human, but somehow "inherits godhood" from an alien, whose species is very long lived. IIRC this is one of the old-style god thingies, i.e. "god of thunder" not "omniscient omnipotent omnipresent transcendent being".

The plot somehow revolved around identifying and fighting some enemy which, I believe, was in turn a member of the alien species who acted as the avatar of the opposite god in the alien pantheon.

The only thing I remember for sure is that the enemy was identified as "green green" or "gringrin" (sadly, I read this in translation so I am not sure what the original meant)

Comment: Is it the "Lord of Light" by Roger Zelazny? It's all about humans who inherit alien tech and become Hindu gods. If so, I'll turn this into an answer...

Comment: I think not cause the gods are from an alien pantheon, and I believe there is only one human with this condition. But it might have been another from Zelazny.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This sounds like "[Isle of the Dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isle_of_the_Dead_(Zelazny_novel))", by Roger Zelazny, published in 1969.

> ... he sought out a mentor, who happened to be a member of a very
>   long-lived and slowly dying alien race, the Pei'ans. Under this
>   tutelage, Sandow eventually became a telepath and "worldscaper". ... Sandow is bound to "Shimbo of Darktree, Shrugger of Thunders" ... 
>   it is believed that the worldscaper is actually acting as an avatar
>   for the god. ... Gringrin vowed revenge on the other worldscapers,
>   starting with Sandow. Somehow Gringrin has been able to unite himself
>   with Belion (Shimbo's traditional enemy in Pei'an mythology).

Comment: ah, yes, that is exactly it, thanks!

Comment: One of Zelazny's more minor works, I think, but still worth a re-read